# How should I get the Backbone.Marionette.Application using requireJs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I decided to divide my `web app` in different `Apps` (app1, app2).

Why from `js/app1.js` I get `undefined`?
How should I access the mainApp from the app1 using requirejs?

Here's my code:

---

**js/main.js**

```
require([
    'js/app',
    'js/app1/app1',
    'js/app2/app2'
],
function (App)
{
    "use strict";
    App.initialize();
});
```

---

**js/mainApp.js**

```
define([''],
function(app)
{
    var mainApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    mainApp.start();

    mainApp.initialize = function() {
        Backbone.history.start();
    }

    return  mainApp;
});
```

---

**js/app1/app1.js**

```
define(['js/mainApp],
function(app)
{
    console.log(app); // undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With require.js, if there is an error in one of the required file, sometimes it doesn't show as an error but the return value becomes undefined. In your case, `app` in `js/app1/app1.js` is undefined most likely due to an error in `js/mainApp.js`.

Just from the code you provided, `js/mainApp.js` has a `define` statement with an empty string, but expects `App` to be passed to it's function. Try removing the empty string and just pass an empty list (`[]`) to `define`, and not pass `App` to the function there.

If your actual code doesn't have these syntax problems but you're still getting `undefined`, please update the code snippets in your question.

Try this:

**js/mainApp.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.marionette'],
function($, _, Backbone)
{
    var mainApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    // Make sure main app is not undefined here.
    console.log('mainApp:', mainApp);  

    mainApp.start();

    mainApp.initialize = function() {
        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return  mainApp;
});
```

Don't forget to provide the correct path for the JS libraries.

Comment: +1 thanks for your time. Actually I am pretty sure there are no error in my js files. I rewrote my questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070038/how-to-define-controller-router-and-app-in-the-right-order-using-requirejs. please take a look.